# How to create templates in Kentico 9?

Tags: kentico

I need to create few templates for E-commerce site. Can anyone guide me as how to create templates in Kentico 9 ? There is an existing site and I need to create five other templates for the same. Am totally new to Kentico.

Please help.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look in the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-the-portal-engine/editing-page-layouts) and [tutorial](https://docs.kentico.com/k9tutorial/creating-page-templates) first. Try to follow the steps described and if you have a more specific question come back here and edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many generic templates in Kentico, so you could clone any of them and modify to your needs - this might be easier for you to edit existing one as you'll have an example.

I'd recommend you to take following steps:

1. Go to Pages application in Kentico administration
2. Select any page in content tree on the left
3. go to properties -> template
4. Save as new template (so you do not screw up exting one) and save your changes
5. Switch to Design tab - this is where you build/configure you template

On the Design tab there is green line with template name and hamburger menu, where you can choose edit layout - this is where you can implement markup of the page as well as split your page into zones. After you accomplish html for you page save changes and close current dialog.

Now you should be back to Design tab. Here you can add web parts to zones you've specified in the layout. There is huge amount of different web parts (user controls). All they have different purpose and settings, so you should check documentation and figure out which one should be used in your particular case.
Try editable text, editable image, repeater, navigation in order to get an idea how it works.